# Referencing chapters

Tags: cross-referencing, chapters, capitalization

By searching for posts on referencing chapters for thesis in this webpage, I came up for the following solution coding:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,nameref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[nokeyprefix]{refstyle}

\begin{document}

In this section, we will explain the method used to tackle this
problem but the actual calculation and results will appear later on in
\chapref{chap:3}, \chapref{chap:4} and \chapref{chap:5}. The main
theorem is as follows.

\end{document}
```

The problem is as in the figure. The letter 'C' in 'chapter' is small case. How to make it big case? 
[image]

Comment: Advice, do not label your chapters, figures, tables, or references using numbers. Give them names. Think of them as little children. I wouldn't dare to call my kids *Number one* and *Number two*.

Comment: @Johannes_B It'd be a talking point, though, wouldn't it? ;)

Comment: Use `\Chapref`. And better use a clas that really has chapters.

Comment: Why use capital letter? It only disturb reading without giving anything to the meaning.

Comment: @Sveinung the word chapter here is referring to a specific chapter and conventionally it would be capitalised. It could be left lower case if the sentence said something like "later on in chapters 3-5", as that's referring to a generic group of chapters.

Comment: Still, I cannot see any use for the capital letter. A reference to chapter 3 cannot be misunderstood.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thank you for your suggestions. And \Chapref worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the uppercase version of the commands as seen on page one of the documentation.

[image: sharinaismailCleverref]

```
\documentclass{report}
%\usepackage{xparse,nameref}% unneded
%\usepackage{cleveref}% unneded
%\usepackage{filecontents}% Load this only if you know what it is doing
\usepackage[nokeyprefix]{refstyle}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Wombat}\label{wombat}
\chapter{Capybara}\label{capybara}
\chapter{Duck}\label{duck}

In this section, we will explain the method used to tackle this problem but the actual
calculation and results will appear later on in \Chapref{duck}, \Chapref{wombat} and
\Chapref{capybara}. The main theorem is as follows.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The package `cleveref` has the option `capitalise`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

In this section, we will explain the method used to tackle this
problem but the actual calculation and results will appear later on in
\cref{bla}, \cref{blub}. The main
theorem is as follows.

\chapter{bla}
\label{bla}

\chapter{blub}
\label{blub}

\end{document}
```

[image]